# Siblings to the right only or using $(ID).something.$(ID2).something or next()

Tags: jquery

I have a html layout as such:-

```
<div id="left-column" style="200px"></div>
<div id="center-column"></div>
<div id="right-column"></div>
```

In the left column i have some links with the functions like the  below, one to grow the center column the other to shrink it.

At the moment:-

```
OPTION 1 does both left and right columns

OPTION 2 works but throws an error in IE SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method '$' which refers to the .$('#right....

OPTION 3 works growing but does not shrinking
```

any ideas guys?

Thanks

```
//GROWING
//OPTION 1:
    $('#center-column').animate({ width: '0px' }, 500).siblings().animate({ 'width': ($(window).width() - cLeft) + 'px' });
//OPTION 2:
    $('#center-column').animate({ width: '0px' }, 500).$('#center-column').animate({ 'width': ($(window).width() - cLeft) + 'px' });
//OPTION 3:    
$('#center-column').animate({ width: '0px' }, 500).next().animate({ 'width': ($(window).width() - cLeft) + 'px' });

//SHRINKING
        var rightwidth = $(window).width() - (cCenter + cLeft + cMargin);
//OPTION1
        $('#center-column').animate({ width: cCenter + 'px' }, 500).next().animate({ 'width': rightwidth + 'px' });
//OPTION2
        $('#center-column').animate({ width: cCenter + 'px' }, 500).siblings().animate({ 'width': rightwidth + 'px' });
//OPTION3:
        $('#center-column').animate({ width: cCenter + 'px' }, 500).$('#right-column').animate({ 'width': rightwidth + 'px' });
```

Comment: Option 2 is throwing the error because you cannot chain jQuery the way you are doing it, you'd need a `;` in between the two calls: `$(sel).doA(); $(sel).doB();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//GROWING
    //OPTION 2:
        $('#center-column').animate({width: '0px'}, 500, function() {
            $('#center-column').animate({'width': ($(window).width() - cLeft) + 'px'});
        });

//SHRINKING
    //OPTION3:
        $('#center-column').animate({width: cCenter + 'px'}, 500, function() {
            $('#right-column').animate({'width': rightwidth + 'px'});
        })
```